# is there a continuous $f\colon [1,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ where $\lim f$ is $0$ at $\infty$ but integral of $f(x) / x$ is divergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

I've been struggling with finding a counter example to a question regarding to the limit comparison test.
The false statement is that for every $f(x)$ that is defined and continuous $[1, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$, if : $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$$ then the following integral exists (does not diverge):
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{f(x)} xdx$$

I've been trying to use weird functions like $\frac{\ln(x)}{x^{0.1}}$ and to choose a function that will make $\frac{f(x)}x$ have an asymptote at $x=1$ but couldn't find anything robust to counter this false statement.

Thanks in regards!

Comment: What about $f(x)=\frac{1}{ln(x+1)}$?

Comment: @Forester Not defined for $x=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one: $f\colon[1,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ defined by
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\ln(1+x)}
$$
Note that
$$\begin{align*}
\int_1^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}dx &= \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x\ln(1+x)}dx\\
&\geq \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x)\ln (x+1) }dx \\
&= \int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x\ln x }dx = \infty
\end{align*}$$
since a primitive of $\frac{1}{x\ln x}$ is $\ln\ln x$.

Comment: works! thank you very much!!!

Comment: Glad this helped!